# <Audio> el added by js skips, but audio added into HTML works just fine

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I've been trying to figure this out for a long time, and I don't understand what the issue is.

If I add an `<Audio>` HTML element on the page itself, the song loads and plays just fine; no skipping.

When I add a `new Audio()` in js, set the src, and insert it into the HTML, it skips. What is different from it? I've matched them 1:1 with the settings (autoload, etc) and they act differently. Maybe I'm doing something incorrectly?

I'll attach the CodePen. I had some test functions, but even just placing the Audio (when those are commented out) don't work 1:1. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

https://codepen.io/jrhager84/pen/VwLoXKX

Answer (score 0):

I spend a lot of time for debugging case "why videos with sound can't use autoplay"? And i found that it's stucks on browsers policy.

Comment: It plays now and cors is set. It's not set to auto play either.